# FTP - IIS 7.5 - Stop / Deny Directory Listing

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ftp

FTP site is hosted in IIS 7.5. Anonymous users are allowed. I want to restrict users to browse the directories in the FTP site and allow them only if they know the full path. Can it be achieved ? If so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files and folders that are *direct* physical children of the FTP root can't be hidden. You could mark these files and folders as hidden in explorer, but that only prevents the most casual of browsers from seeing subfolders and files. It is still possible to override this using `ls -a` in the ftp client.

You can only control directory browsing of *virtual* directories in an IIS FTP 7.5 site. i.e. where you've right clicked on the site and added a virtual directory mapped to a folder *not under* the FTP site root:

[image]

They look like this when added:

[image]

To control their visibility open the directory browsing feature:

[image]

Uncheck the *Virtual Directories* directory listing option then click `Apply`:

[image]

There's also no support to control directory browsing in the [FTP Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723667%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) hooks either which was another place I've looked at in the past.

If you need more fine grained level of control over your FTP site then you're going to have to replace IIS FTP with a more featured FTP server such as Filezilla (free) or [Gene6 FTP](http://www.g6ftpserver.com/) (commercial) which is a product we use (it has a COM configuration API which is even callable from .NET apps via interop).